# Drupal, Views: using AJAX to load the complete node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've a View page with all the content of my website (the node headers). When I click on one of these header I would like to load the complete node without refreshing the page and display it on the left.

Can I do this with Views (I mean.. does it have a functionality to load a complete node and add it to the current page ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Views is basically an SQL query generator. You can do what you describe with javascript, but I don't know what modules might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible using Views. Views is much more than just SQL generator.
Views can work with Fields, or with full node. Set it to full node.
Views can work with Ajax - set it to "yes" (I think it is Yes by default).

It is hard from your description to understand the whole picture, so I can't lead you any further. All I can say is that I use Exposed Filter with Ajax and load full node properly, chaning the content of the page.

Hope I helped,
You are welcome to ask me directly for further support.

Regards,
Shushu

Answer (score 0):

Check out Modal Frame - http://drupal.org/project/modalframe

Basically, your view displays just the title, and you have "link title to node" enabled.  Rather than jumping to node page, u want to display node content in modal frame pop up.